# How to get the balance of an integrated address?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, integrated-address, balance, unlocked-balance

As an integrated address is different from a subaddress and account hierarchy, how do I get the balance of an integrated address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integrated address is just a normal address with an embedded payment ID. Thus you use the usual [get_balance](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_balance) RPC method, or `balance detail` CLI command.

As they have a payment ID, you can also make use of [get_payments](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_payments) (RPC) and `payments <PID>` (CLI), which will show you any incoming payments made to the address using the provided payment ID.

It's worth pointing out you should not use integrated addresses / payment IDs, as these are deprecated in favor of using subaddresses.

Comment: payments <paymentId> (CLI) - It says that paymentID should be 16 or 64 character hex string, previously asked for 16 / 64 character long paymentId what should I do for get balance of an integrated address?

Comment: Does integrated address map as SubAddress map under indexes of An accounts?

Comment: When you created your integrated address you will have specified the payment ID. It is that payment ID you use for `payments <payment ID>`.

Comment: "Does integrated address map as SubAddress map under indexes of An accounts?" <- It's would be account index 0 subaddress index 0 because an integrated address is a normal address with an embedded payment ID. Your "normal" wallet address (or "main" if you prefer), is at 0,0.

Comment: In Monero wallet cli I am not able to see my integrated address or its details under **account** command which will show all accounts, even with address 0/1/2 command I am not able to see integrated address.

Comment: `address all` will show you all addresses. Note however that an integrated address is just the normal address with an embedded payment ID.

Comment: Yes, got this that integrated address is just normal address, but address all is giving only Primary Address of my wallet. Not integrated address.

Comment: Your integrated address *is* your primary address. Payments made to it go to your normal address with a payment id. Hence you can use `payments pid` to find specific incoming txs made using the payment id.